# How to use NgRx 8 actions with NgRx 7 reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular8, ngrx-store

I'm using the `NgRx` library in my new Angular 8 project. I've been told that they create the actions using `createAction` i.e. `NgRx 8` but they create the reducers using `NgRx 7`. I was given a task in which I used `NgRx 8` for my reducer which I now have to change to `NgRx 7`. My actions and reducer are as below:

**book.actions.ts**

```js
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Book } from "./book";

export const BeginGetBooksAction = createAction("BeginGetBooks");

export const SuccessGetBooksAction = createAction(
  "SuccessGetBooks",
  props<{ payload: Book[] }>()
);

export const BeginAddBookAction = createAction(
  "BeginAddBook",
  props<{ payload: Book }>()
);

export const SuccessAddBookAction = createAction(
  "SuccessAddBook",
  props<{ payload: Book[] }>()
);
```

**book.reducer.ts**

```js
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as BooksActions from "./book.action";
import { Book } from "./book";

export interface BooksState {
  Books: Book[];
  ReadBooks: { book: Book; addedOn: Date }[];
  WantToReadBooks: { book: Book; addedOn: Date }[];
  editBook: Book;
}

const initialState: BooksState = {
  Books: [],
  ReadBooks: [],
  WantToReadBooks: [],
  editBook: new Book()
};

export function booksReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BooksActions.BeginGetBooksAction.type:
      return state;

    case BooksActions.SuccessGetBooksAction.type:
      return { ...state, Books: action.payload };

    case BooksActions.BeginAddBookAction.type:
        return state;

    case BooksActions.SuccessAddBookAction.type:
        return { ...state, Books: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I get an error for `action.payload`

```
Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action'.
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong???

Answer (score 5):

I wrote down a comparison in [NgRx creator functions 101](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/ngrx-creator-functions-101).

In the article you can see how you can combine the syntax of both versions:

```
export const addToCart = createAction(
  // action's type
  '[Product List] Add to cart',
  // optional payload
  props<{ sku: string }>(),
)
export const removeFromCart = createAction(
  '[Product List] Remove from cart',
  props<{ sku: string }>(),
)

export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ReturnType<typeof addToCart> | ReturnType<typeof removeFromCart>,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case addToCart.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: {
          ...state.cartItems,
          [action.sku]: (state.cartItems[action.sku] || 0) + 1,
        },
      }

    case removeFromCart.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: {
          ...state.cartItems,
          [action.sku]: Math.max((state.cartItems[action.sku] || 0) - 1, 0),
        },
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer is good, just your type definition is the problem. You use a plain `Action` type where payload doesn't exists. Try another type definition, like `any` or try union types, but when you try union types, you need all named imports from the action file.
I think the best solution for you is the next generation syntax of reducer, try use the new format.